# How to stop a MATLAB while-loop when the difference between two loop calculated values becomes small

Tags: matlab, while-loop

I currently am working on a school project where I need to calculate the terminal velocity of a sphere falling through liquid as well as how long it takes to reach terminal velocity. Terminal velocity is considered to be reached when the difference between two calculated velocities is less than .0001 m/s. The equation is a function of time and I am planing on using a while loop to perform this being I do not know how long it will take to be reached. I was planning on bumping up my time variable by .1 seconds after each loop. However, I do not know how to stop the loop as I do not know what the velocity will be. It would be very helpful if anyone could point me in the right direction with this. I am wondering how to stop the while loop or if there is another way to perform this calculation?

```
y=0;
while y==0
oldvel = 2;
newvel = 0; 
dal = 2700; %Density of aluminum kg/m^3
dgl = 1260; %Density of Glycerin kg/m^3
g = 9.81; %Gravitational acceleration m/s^2
k = .0018; %Constant incorporating properties of glycerin and sphere geometry kg/m
x = menu('Calculating Terminal Velocity of a Sphere','Continue to Calculation','Exit Program');

if x == 1;
    r = input('Input radius of sphere in meters = ');
    V = (4/3)*pi*(r^3); %Volume of sphere in meters cubed
    t = .1;
    while (abs(oldvel - newvel)<.0001);
        t = .1
        t = t + .1;
        newvel = oldvel;
        newvel = ((((V*(dal-dgl)*g*k))^(1/2))*((tanh(t*(((V*(dal-dgl)*g*k))^(1/2))/(V*dal)))));
    end %end while
    t
    newvel
    elseif x == 2;
    disp('Goodbye')
    y=1;
end
end %end if
```

This is what I currently have and it kicks out of the loop instantly with newvel=0 and t=0. I ran the numbers in excel and if I set t=0 originally then the velocity is 0 and the loop would not work, however, I set t=.1 which should correct the issue but it does not.

Comment: `t = .1;  t = t + .1;` doesn't do anything but set `t=0.2` every iteration. Probably not what you want. Remove the `t=0.1` statement. Just for good coding practise in general: it's not often appreciated to have the program print progress reports in the form of variables with omitted semi-colon. Usually there's no visual updates each loop iteration and if that's wanted a `disp` with a string is made.

Comment: With these corrections the program enters an infintie loop. I am not sure what could be wrong. If I change the while statement to oldvel-newvel>1 instead of .0001 then it will work for one iteration but I need it for .0001. @Adriaan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while abs(OldVel - NewVel)>1e-4
    NewVel = OldVel; %// make the current velocity the old one
    NewVel = (..)    %// calculate some new velocity
end
```

The loop will terminate whenever the statement is untrue, thus as soon as your velocity difference goes below the 0.0001 m/s the while loop will stop and the variabel `NewVel` will contain your terminal velocity.